# YouCompleteMe Doesn't Find System Headers with compile_commands.json

Tags: vim, clang, youcompleteme

On the YouCompleteMe Documentation, there are two options for setting up support for C/C++ semantic support. The first is using a compilation database with CMake (e.g. the file compile_commands.json) and the second is using a .ycm_extra_conf.py. Luckily, I am using Cmake so I am able to generate a compilation database. YouCompleteMe works ok for sources in my project however, it is not able to find headers for the following files: system headers (e.g. iostream) and it cannot find header files included in external projects in my project (i.e. git submodules in combination with with CMake ExternalProject_Add(...)). What wasn't clear for me from the documentation was whether or not I should use a combination of the ycm_extra_conf.py and the compile_commands.json. Can someone give me some advice on why my compilation database doesn't have sufficient information in it for me to find all the necessary header files?